# pass the arraylist with hashmap between activities in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I want to send the arraylist with hashmap between activities but is give me null arraylist with hashmap.

Sender Activity

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> childgame = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
Intent ordernow= new Intent(CategoryActivity.this,OrderDetailActivity.class);
ordernow.putExtra("orderlist",childgame);                                     
startActivity(ordernow);
```

Receiver Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle =intent.getExtras();
bundle.getSerializable("orderlist");
```

Comment: Try this `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("orderlist")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `putExtra(String, Serializable)` to pass the value in an Intent and `getSerializableExtra(String)` method to retrieve the data.

ArrayList implements `Serializable`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

You already have this

```
ordernow.putExtra("orderlist",childgame);
```

To get the list

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("orderList");
```

`public Serializable getSerializableExtra (String name)`

Added in API level 1

Retrieve extended data from the intent.

Parameters

name    The name of the desired item.

Returns

the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or null if no Serializable value was found.

Comment: thanks is worked for me but is give me  Type safety: Unchecked cast from Serializable to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> this suppress warning  so if i add Add@SuppressWarning is create any problem in future or older version

Comment: its a lint warning about  the cast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings. here's one link that can help. its for type safety and its a lint warning. better to check the type cast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089151/android-getchild-edittext-values-on-button-click-in-expandablelistview help me in this question

Comment: why don't you ask a new question. i am sure the community can answer. i have not worked a lot on expandable listview. Any way i will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

try by using  **`getIntent().getSerializableExtra("orderlist")`**

**on Receiver side use :** same type of ArrayList to receive data !

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("orderlist");
```