# How can I pass a list between activities?

Tags: android, list, android-intent, android-activity

I need pass a List with objects Between activities.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thank's.

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass the arraylist with hashmap between activities in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629379/pass-the-arraylist-with-hashmap-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of list are you trying to pass? Are the contents of the list custom objects or regular built-in classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object's class must implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then you can pass it as an extra

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putSerializableExtra("key",yourList);  // or putParcelableExtra
```